# Saving modified existing object vs copy with modified fields

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like to ask for advice about Spring JPA and hibernate during modifying objects. Maybe it depends on design pattern or something.

There are two possibilities:

1. Copy existing object (create new reference) modify and save copy as object.
2. Modify existing object (without changing reference) and save.

Could you answer and explain why/when use which ?

Comment: There is a third option: represent what is changed as some kind of `Command` and decorate the object with the `Command`. Then you could execute all `Command`s before saving the object back to database, creating a new instance.

Comment: You mean this command should create new instance from existing object and modified? Should it be service  function/method ?

Comment: What I mean: collect all the `Command`s that would change an object, execute them all just before commiting to database to create one fresh, up-to-date object. See [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Usually Modifying existing entity is preferable way. It's more reliable/less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is intended to be used in the way you describe as option 1:

Load an entity, modify it and (implicitly) save it when the transaction/session gets committed.